# Drawing 3D Planar Surfaces

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit

I'm hoping to draw several planar surfaces in 3D space in Swift using SceneKit. Specifically, the surfaces will all reside within a hyperboloid. I've never drawn custom shapes/objects before, and I've gotten quite lost trying to make sense of  the documentation.

Any advice on the reqs/guidelines for customizing surfaces in 3D space?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should take a look at the [`+[SCNGeometry geometryWithSources:elements:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNGeometry_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SCNGeometry/geometryWithSources:elements:) method in addition to the [SCNGeometrySource](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNGeometrySource_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SCNGeometrySource) and [SCNGeometryElement](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNGeometryElement_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SCNGeometryElement) classes.

Finally you can find an example in the "SceneKit Slides for WWDC 2014" sample code. Look for `-mobiusStripWithSubdivisionCount:` in [AAPLSlideCreatingGeometries.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SceneKitWWDC2014/Listings/Scene_Kit_Session_WWDC_2014_Sources_Slides_AAPLSlideCreatingGeometries_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014551-Scene_Kit_Session_WWDC_2014_Sources_Slides_AAPLSlideCreatingGeometries_m-DontLinkElementID_43)

Comment: I don't see how a custom SCNGeometry will allow for a smooth, curved plane? Is there an alternative method a la Bezier surfaces? @mnuages

Comment: SceneKit can only deal with discretized surfaces (triangles). You can make this surface appear smooth by specifying the actual normal at each vertex. In the provided example the Möbius strip looks smooth even if it's a discretization version of the surface.

Comment: Thanks @mnuages. So I must specify an arbitrary amount of triangles for any surface? There's no way to automate the process by using some sort of "triangle generator" so to speak?

Comment: no, you will have to discretize the surface yourself, refining the discretization according to the desired smoothness and curvature of the survace